# How to edit .htaccess file on Bigcommerce site?

Tags: .htaccess, webdav, webfonts, bigcommerce

My web font licence requires me to edit my .htaccess file.

I can't see the .htaccess file in WebDav, is it possible to edit this file on a Bigcommerce site?

Comment: That depends on how webdav is implemented on your site. Maybe there currently is no such file? Maybe it is hoffen from you? How should _we_ know all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigCommerce doesn't have an .htaccess file for a couple of reasons

1. Servers are NGINX, not Apache
2. It is a multi-tenant environment

There should be alternative methods for using your desired font. If you have questions or need to explore those options, it would be great if you could provide more details.

Comment: Well that would be why I couldn't find it! Thanks.

If I upload the font files (embedded-opentype, woff2, woff and truetype) is there a way to stop people from being able to download / hotlink them?

Comment: @Alistair  If it is on our severs, we'd see any malicious activity for hotlinking and be able to address it. As for downloading, I'm not sure that there are more granular controls available.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to edit the .htaccess file on the BigCommerce SAAS platform.